# Can anyone help me with the Make, Model (version), and Unit of this WWII army trainer. Appears to be an AT-6 version

Tags: military, aviation-history, wwii, propeller-aircraft, trainer

[image]Location: Madison, WI Municipal Airport on May 21, 1939.

Notice the straight bottom on the vertical stabilizer, crest emblem, pitot tubes, landing gear, exhaust location, antenna, etc.

I have two photos of this plane, the 2nd photo is from the front, but I don't know how to add a second photo to this post.

Comment: I am interested in the second photo as well, mainly because the landing gear. I don't see any gear door on the wheels as I see in other BC-1's but also no wheel fairings as seen on most other NA-16 derivatives without retractable gear. I also expect an antenna (circular antenna) below the engine. If there is a limitation on the number of pictures new contributors can include in a question, can you try to write an answer and include it in there? I can then move it to the question for you.

Comment: Hi DeltaLima, My sincere appreciation for your response.  I found I actually have 2 more photos of this plane but cannot find how to post them.  I know it can be done because I received a response from another question where the comment included photos.  If anyone can teach me how to add photos, please do.  Having said that, yes, it has a circular antenna below the engine. The landing gear does not appear to be retractable. There is a protruding tube or antenna about 12" long and about 12" in from the tip of the right wing. Both wings appear to have landing lights. Exhaust is life side only.

Comment: DeltaLima - I think you nailed it with the NA BC-1 in that I've looked at several photos that match this plane except for the landing gear.  This plane definitely has fixed landing gear. Was there a model of the BC-1 that had fixed landing gear?  Also, I'm curious about the crest emblem on the side of the fuselage. P.S. It doesn't appear to be an NA-16 from all the photos I've seen.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: as far as I know there was no BC-1 with fixed gear, but there also wasn't any fixed gear version with the rudder shaped like the one in your picture. It may have been an early prototype that ended up with the Technical Training command for the purpose of ... technical training.

Comment: Thank you, DeltaLima.  Your knowledge is exceptional.  I'm sorry I don't know how I can add my other two photos of this plane.  I tried to upload them in my original post and wasn't able to do it. I see no way to attach them later with a comment. Thank you again for all your help.  I feel it is not only important but necessary to have historical photos accurately labeled with as much information as possible. You have certainly enabled me to do that.

Comment: @FreshBreeze simply [edit] your post, place the cursor where you want the image to appear, then drag the other images into the edit box. The "add picture" dialog will automatically come up with the pic preloaded and all you have to do is hit "OK".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is a North American NA-36, BC-1, [a North American NA-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_NA-16) derivative, the predecessor of the  [North American T-6 Texan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan)

[image: North American BC-1 with marking 31]

<sub>Source: [nationalmuseum.af.mil](https://www.nationalmuseum.af.mil/Upcoming/Photos/igphoto/2000538187/)</sub>

Some observations that helped to determine the precise model:

- The fuselage is covered with fabric. Later models used metal
- The trailing edge of the rudder is rounded, later models had a straight rudder
- The bottom corner of the rudder is squared, some other models are rounded (e.g BT-9)
- The fuselage shows the crest of the [USAAF's Technical Training Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Division,_Air_Training_Command):

[image: The crest of the USAAF's Technical Training Command, similar to the one shown on the fuselage of the aircraft in the question]

<sub>Source: [Picturing Meteorology](https://picturingmeteorology.com/home/2017/12/22/gi-dinner-christmas-1943). The text "Sustineo Alas" is latin for: "I sustain the wings", or more loosely translated: "I keep em flying"</sub>

The aircraft belonged likely to Chanute Field Technical Training Command (Illinois), located some 200 miles south of Madison.

Comment: You have amazing research and/or aircraft identification skills!

Comment: DeltaLima, I agree with Jamiec on your exceptional skills.  I believe you not only identified the aircraft but also its unit and home base.  I still find it interesting that the plane you posted is essentially identical even to include the position of the propeller, yours #31 vs mine #32, but yours has retractable landing gear and mine is fixed.  I wish I could add my two other photos so you could see them. Thank you VERY much for your research and identification.

Comment: P.S.  I have yet another plane I'd like ID'd, It is similar but is a biplane and I have failed to find a photo on the internet to help me identify it. I hope you will see my posted question and l look forward to your help if you see it.  Again, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @FreshBreeze, you're welcome. Keep em coming!

Answer (score 0):

This fine aircraft (according to the directors of many WWII aviation films) is the Messerschmitt Bf-109G

(Couldn't resist the joke, sorry)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't an AGM-Zero? I'm sure I saw it in a movie...